# RSA private key revealing by decrypting c=n-1

Tags: rsa, side-channel-attack

In RSA, if we use Square and always Multiply algorithm in decryption, how does decrypting the ciphertext $c=n-1$, while our public key is $(n,e)$, cause the private key $d$ to reveal due to side-channel attack?

Comment: What is the origin of this question and what did you try?

Comment: Hello. Side-channel attack, and specifically Square and always Multiply algorithm in decryption. I did not get anything.

Comment: Like this one https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/75419/18298 and **hint:** $n-1 \equiv -1 \bmod n$ this just make easier, nothing more.

Comment: For decrypting $c=n-1$ by square and always multiply algorithm, according to bits of $d$, we have to handle $1$ or $-1$ in every step; if current bit of $d$ is 1, our output in that step is $-1$ and if current bit of $d$ is $0$ we will have $1$. But I don't understand the relation of this to side-channel attack. Does the power consumption change?

Comment: Well, you got it. start from coding on which you measure the time. Use preferable C++ and Chrono timing. _Does the power consumption change?_ Yes. if $d=1$ then squaring and multiplication with 1 is free? You need to investigate the cases..

Comment: "Square and always multiply" is not well-known: I had to [Google it](https://www.google.com/search?q="Square+and+always+Multiply") to get a [relevant link](https://orenlab.sise.bgu.ac.il/AttacksonImplementationsCourseBook/03_Temporal_SC_2). In short, it's square and multiply modified to perform multiplication and discard it's result when the exponent bit is 0.

Comment: @fgrieu isn't it the second version on my answer. Now, I've named it, thanks.