How to Convert a Point from secp256k1 to secp384r1 in Elliptic Curve Cryptography
I'm working with elliptic curve cryptography and have a generator point $G$ on the secp256k1 curve. For example, I can express a point as $5G$ (the result of multiplying the generator point by 5).

Can the point $5G$ from secp256k1 be converted to an equivalent point on secp384r1? If so, how can I achieve this?

Is there a direct method to translate a point from secp256k1 to an equivalent point on secp384r1?


I appreciate any guidance on how to manage the conversion of elliptic curve points while maintaining the integrity of my cryptographic operations.

https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/108258/36960

@DannyNiu I'm not trying to get a public key from the private key

You should learn from your previous question that elliptic-curve discrete logarithm is a hard problem and what you're trying to do is not possible.

Think about it this way: different elliptic curves are domain-separated by their equation. Just as it's meaningless to go to New York in Wales (US and UK are different countries), it's equally meaningless to get a point on one curve that "corresponds to" a point on another different curve.

I don't really get how this involves solving discrete logarithm

I'll try to explain how this involves solving the discrete logarithm. The two curves you are looking at have NOTHING to do with each other.
Therefore the only way you could conceivably think of converting from one to the other is start with $kG$ in Curve 1, solve DL to get $G$ and then pick a generator $G'$ in Curve 2, and compute $kG'$ in Curve 2.

OP asked a question stemming from a similar confusion before, and I linked to an answer in that post. If he still don't learn by now, then no point teach him anymore.
